# AWS error "Exceeded attempts to wait" when deploying a stack into cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, opensearch

in this stack deployment, the changes includes:

1. upgrade open search from version `1.0` to `1.3`
2. increase volume size from `500` to `1024`

the deployment taking longer time than usual, about 4hours later, the open search successfully upgraded to `1.3` but the storage volume size are not.

when we check back the event of the stack deployment, the deployment was failed as attached screenshot.

the deployment was failed and the rollback was failed also.
we not sure whether we can rollback to `1.0` to redeploy again or if we skip, open search might detach from our stack configuration.

any idea how these error come to? and how can we solve this?

[image: error in stack event]
[image: rollback dialog]

we not sure what we can do to this yet, we suspecting due to our open search have huge amount of data then it takes longer time than usual. is there any timeout that causing stack deployment to fail?

Answer (score 0):

We have experienced similar issues and basically what helped us was to initially continue the rollout skipping the OpenSearch domain. Then running deployment once again, so the states in both stack and OpenSearch service are consistent.

The weird thing in our case (since we upgraded volume type along with higher OS version) was that the domain itself managed to upgrade, but volume type did not. To solve this we repeated the procedure above twice -> the first deployment after failure also failed from CloudFormation side, but the domain updated to the desired state. Then rolling back, skipping domain and second redeployment did the job.